# Reactive or observe in dynamic filtering

Tags: dynamic, filter, reactive

I have a working app that uses multiple filters to plot some data and i want the filters to be dynamic and dependent on the filter above by only showing available options for the selection.  For instance if the Location_Id == 1 then only 'Bike' User_Type is available in the 'User Type' filter.  This all works when the app starts with the filters all constrained by the initial Location_ID starting value but as soon as i change the initial input (Location_Id) nothing is getting updated automatically and i have to do an Select All to see which data is available for the new selected Location Id.  I have been reading all morning and it seems i need to perhaps include a reactive() somewhere in the server but its not clear how then i update the ui and if i need a render type function somewhere.

```
#Example for stack overflow
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(lubridate)
#Create test data
set.seed(10)
Dates. <- sample(c(seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date("2017-12-28"),1),seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),as.Date("2019-12-28"),1)),1000)
Facility_Type. <- sample(c("Bikelane","No facility"),length(Dates.),replace = T)
Data.. <- data.frame(Date = Dates., Facility_Type = Facility_Type.)
Data..$User_Type_Desc<- sample(c("Bike","Pedestrian"),nrow(Data..),replace = T)
Data..$Counts <- sample(1:100,nrow(Data..),replace = T)
Data..$Location_Id <- sample(c("01","02","03","04"),nrow(Data..),replace = T)
Data..$Month <- months(Data..$Date)
Data..$Year <- year(Data..$Date)
Data..$User_Type_Desc <- as.character(Data..$User_Type_Desc)
Data..$Facility_Type <- as.character(Data..$Facility_Type)

#Force some changes on data to highlight problem 
Data..$User_Type_Desc[Data..$Location_Id%in%"01"] <- "Bike"
Data..$User_Type_Desc[Data..$Location_Id%in%"04"] <- "Pedestrian"


ui <- 
  #shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Bend Bike/PedTraffic Counts",
             #Graphics panel
             tabPanel("Charting",
                      #headerPanel(title = "Bend Traffic Count Data Viewer"),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          #Select Location Id
                          selectInput("Location_Id","Select a Location Id",choices = unique(Data..$Location_Id)),

                          #Select Year
                          pickerInput(inputId = "Year", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", choices = NULL, 
                                      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE),
                          #Select Month
                          pickerInput(inputId = "Month", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", choices = NULL, 
                                      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE),
                          #Location details
                          ##################
                          #Select User Types 
                          pickerInput(inputId = "User_Type", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", choices = NULL, 
                                      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE),
                          #Select Facility Types
                          pickerInput(inputId = "Facility_Type", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", choices = NULL, 
                                      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` = "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE)
                          #dateRangeInput("Date", "Input date range")
                          #selectInput("Date","Select a Product",choices = NULL)


                          #Panel end
                        ),
                        mainPanel( plotOutput("location_plot"))
                        #Sidebar panel layout end  
                      )
                      # Sidebar panel end
             )
             #PAge end   
  )



server <- 
  #print(str(product_list))
  shinyServer(function(session,input,output) {

    #Create selection menus
    ##########################
    #Year selection with choices constrained by Location_Id
    observe({
      Years. <- unique(Data..$Year[Data..$Location_Id%in%input$Location_Id])
      updatePickerInput(session,"Year","Select Year(s)",choices = Years.,selected = Years.[1])
    })
    #Month selection  with Year choices
    observe({
      Months. <- unique(Data..$Month[Data..$Year%in%input$Year])
      updatePickerInput(session,"Month","Select Month(s)",choices = Months., selected = Months.[1]  )

    })
    #User Type
    observe({
      User_Type. <- unique(Data..$User_Type_Desc[Data..$Year%in%input$Year & Data..$Month%in%input$Month])
      updatePickerInput(session,"User_Type","Select User Type(s)",choices = User_Type., selected = User_Type.[1])

    })
    #Facility Type
    observe({
      Facility_Type. <- unique(Data..$Facility_Type[Data..$Year%in%input$Year & Data..$Month%in%input$Month
                                                    & Data..$User_Type_Desc%in%input$User_Type])
      updatePickerInput(session,"Facility_Type","Select Facility Type(s)",choices = Facility_Type., selected = Facility_Type.[1])

    })

    #Plot data
    ##########################
    #Select final data and chart
    output$location_plot <- renderPlot({
      #Select data
      dat <- Data..[Data..$Location_Id%in%input$Location_Id & Data..$Month%in%input$Month & 
                      Data..$Year%in%input$Year & Data..$User_Type_Desc%in%input$User_Type,]
      #Initialze chart
      ggplot(data = dat, x=Date, y = Counts) +
        geom_bar(aes(x = Date,y = Counts),color = "black", position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+
        facet_wrap(Facility_Type~User_Type_Desc)

    })
  })




#Run App

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a solution for the above problem that started this issue (making filters update with proper reactive-ness) but now that i have added a map the app tends to break after making selections in the first selector, in this example that would be the state.

I created a new example below that answers the above question but poses a new one: Why is my app crashing and does it have to do with improper way i handle the reactive-ness?

In order to get the app to crash you have to select a couple of different states and let it render.  It seems to do it on California so it makes me wonder if its a matter of the amount of data the map is attempting to render.  Unfortunately there is no error given RStudio just crashes.  Not sure if this is the proper way to pose this question but if the reactive-ness is the problem with the RStudio crash i think its still relevant to this thread.  Thx for any help!

```
library(shiny)    # for shiny apps
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tigris)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

# Load(Create) data
State_01_Tracts_Sp <- tracts("01")
State_02_Tracts_Sp <- tracts("02")
State_04_Tracts_Sp <- tracts("04")
State_05_Tracts_Sp <- tracts("05")
State_06_Tracts_Sp <- tracts("06")
Tracts_Sp <- rbind(State_01_Tracts_Sp ,State_02_Tracts_Sp, State_04_Tracts_Sp, 
State_05_Tracts_Sp , State_06_Tracts_Sp  )


#Decode fips into descriptive state and county names
Tracts_Sp@data$State <- 
fips_codes$state_name[match(Tracts_Sp@data$STATEFP,fips_codes$state_code)]
Tracts_Sp@data$County <- 
fips_codes$county[match(Tracts_Sp@data$COUNTYFP,fips_codes$county_code)]
#Create a copy of the spatial data's data frame
Data.. <- Tracts_Sp@data



#Set up User Interface
   ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Census Viewer Test"),
  tabsetPanel(
    #Daily Counts Panel
    ##############
    #Hourly Counts Panel
    #######################
    tabPanel("Tab 1",
             #Call plot 
             fluidRow(column(width = 12,plotlyOutput("county_plot" ))),
             #Location Details 
             fluidRow( 
               column(3,
                      h4("Select Details"),
                      uiOutput("State_selector"),
                      uiOutput("County_selector"),
                      uiOutput("Tract_selector")),
               column(6,
                      #h4("Selected Location"),
                      leafletOutput("map_plot",height = 500))
               #Close row
             )
             #Close panel
    )
    #Close setPanel
  )
  #PAge end   
)

#Set up Server
#---------------------------
server <- shinyServer(function(session,input,output){
  #Temporal Details
  ##################
  #State
  output$State_selector <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "State",
                label = "State", multiple = FALSE,
                choices = c( unique(Data..$State)),
                selected =  unique(Data..$State)[1])
  })
  #County selection----
  output$County_selector <- renderUI({
    available0 <- as.character(unique(Data..$County[Data..$State %in% input$State ] 
))
    pickerInput(inputId = "County", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", 
choices = as.character(unique(available0)), 
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` 
= "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE,selected = as.character(unique(available0)))
  })
  #Tract selection----
  output$Tract_selector <- renderUI({
    available1 <- as.character(unique(Data..$GEOID[Data..$State %in% input$State ] ))
    pickerInput(inputId = "Tract", label = "Select/deselect all + format selected", 
  choices = as.character(unique(available1)), 
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10,`selected-text-format` 
= "count > 3"), multiple = TRUE,selected = as.character(unique(available1)))
  })

#Graphics
#Select final data and chart-----

  output$county_plot <- renderPlotly({
    #Select data
    dat <- Data..[Data..$State%in%input$State & Data..$County%in%input$County & 
Data..$GEOID%in%input$Tract ,]
    #Set up axis parameters depending on amount of data 
    angle = 90

    #Initialze chart
    ggplotly(ggplot(data = dat, x=GEOID, y = ALAND, fill = State) +
               geom_bar(aes(x=GEOID, y = ALAND, fill = State),color = "black", 
position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+
                ggtitle(paste("Land Area of Select Counties 
",unique(dat$State),sep="")) + 
               #Center plot
               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
               ylab("LAnd Area") +
               xlab("") +
               guides(color=guide_legend("State")) +
               theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = angle, hjust = 
1),plot.background = element_rect(fill = "darkseagreen"))) %>% layout(dragmode = 
"select") 

  })
  #Select final data and map-----
  output$map_plot <- renderLeaflet({
    #Select data
    Map_Data_Sp <- Tracts_Sp[Tracts_Sp@data$State%in%input$State,]
    class(Map_Data_Sp )
    #Create map 
    Map <- mapview(Map_Data_Sp, map.types = "OpenStreetMap", legend = FALSE, 
col.regions = "red",color = "black",cex = 10)
    Map@map

    #Close map
  })


})
#Run App
shinyApp(ui,server)
```